# Unable to open forms

Tags: plugins, jinitiator

after installing also getting this "IN order to access this application you must install the Oracle JInitiator Plugin version 1.3,1,30. To install this Plugin,Click here to download the oajinit.exe executable. Once the download is complete,double-click the oajinit.exe file to install the plugin. You will be prompted to restart your browser when the installation is complete"

Forms should open in the EBS application